# Error: pjsip gives `mod_sofia` insetad of the actual phone number

Tags: c, pjsip, freeswitch

I am working on project in which I use Sipek Voip for connecting to Freeswitch. Here is the situation:

I have a Sangoma A400 hard. I compiled Freeswitch for Windows and now it works perfectly.
I have also created a Softphone using Sipek Voip SDK and it works well with Freeswitch.

The problem is that, when I have an incoming call, instead of showing the callers number, I get mod_sofia.

I looked at Sipek and all it gets from pjsip is a string containing `<sip:mod_sofia@192.168.2.10:5060>`.

So I went to pjsip and tried to pass the actual phone number to Sipek. I found out there is a function called `pjsua_call_on_incoming` which handles an incoming call.

It takes an argument of type `pjsip_rx_data`. It has a string field (`rdata->msg_info.msg_buf`) which contains the whole message. I tried to replace `<sip:mod_sofia@192.168.2.10:5060>` with the actual number, but it has no effect.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this link](http://code.google.com/p/sipek2/issues/detail?id=17) for tracking the issue. Unfortunately there are hardly any people who can help you out with Open source projects "for free" even on a forum. I just speak from my personal experience. I am facing the same problem, and cannot figure it out till now, though I have solved many issues that I used to face with SIPEK, all on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I've not understood the root of your problem is in FreeSWITCH or in sipek/pjsip.
This entry on FreeSWITCH wiki could help you debug the sip stack in FreeSWITCH:
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_sofia#Debugging_Sofia-SIP
in a way similar to a wireshark capture.
I'm sorry I don't know how to help you trace down the parsing/rendering of msg_info.msg_buf in pjsip.

Answer (score 0):

Add `sip_contact_user=xxxx` in your dialstring.